# Web Application Eclipse JavaEE

Tags: java-ee, tomcat

Estou a desenvolver uma web app no eclipse utilizando Servlets, JSP e JDBC para conectar à base de dados MySQL. Apesar do meu código não apresentar erros na compilação, quando tento fazer Run ao projeto apresenta-se o seguinte erro:
**http://localhost:8080/CourseManagement/**
[image]

Comment: Amigo, apaga essa imagem, e posta o log do tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aprenda essa, tudo o que fica dentro do diretório WEB-INF não é acessível pelo navegador, isso inclui as JavaServer Pages que você colocou lá. Não lembro se isso pode ser burlado, mas a princípio é assim *by design*.

Não que você necessariamente precise deixar fora dele. Faz tempo que não programo isso, mas acho que para fins dos Servlets que atendem as requisições HTTP acessarem de dentro da aplicação web e retornarem essas JSPs elas são acessíveis, mas pelo navegador diretamente não.

Portanto, até onde posso ajudar sugiro pesquisar mais a respeito e mudar a ideia do que está fazendo.

Por conta disso não custa lembrar, JSPs devem ser somente views que recebem dados mastigados e renderizam, idealmente sem qualquer conhecimento de lógica de negócio, muito menos código da camada do modelo de negócio ou de acesso a banco de dados.

A ideia é que as chamadas HTTP no navegador sejam feitas para URLs mapeadas em annotations colocadas antes de cada método dos Servlets, cada um desses métodos atenda uma requisição específica de método HTTP (GET, POST, etc.), esse método do Servlet execute a regra de negócio (por questão de design pode ser melhor que isso não seja feito diretamente e sim talvez chamando um serviço, que é um objeto pertencente à camada de aplicação que por sua vez chama os objetos do modelo de negócio na camada de negócio, lembrando que essas camadas são apenas lógicas, podem só existir conceitualmente e estabelecerem uma relação de dependência ou não-dependência uma da outra).

Aí esses objetos do modelo de negócio chamam os de acesso a dados, e aí a coisas começam a ir pelo caminho inverso e a subir a hierarquia de camadas, os dados vão para o modelo de negócio, que retorna controle para o serviço e este agora passa o controle para uma JSP, que é alimentada com os dados e renderiza o HTML que vai ser exibido pela camada de interface com o usuário.

Pelo menos era assim nos áureos tempos do *server-side rendering*, que foi suplantado pelo AJAX e não sei mais o quê que se usa hoje, mas o princípio de isolamento entre camadas e de ir pulando de uma a outra permanece, bem como ainda se usa arquitetura em camadas (*layered architecture*), que foi o que basicamente descrevi aqui.